# PHP get part of string to new array?

Tags: php, string

If I have an array in the following format, how can I assign part of these array values in to a new array?
(Numeric value `123` and `654` indicate that the array can be separated in these locations)

```
$fruits = array();
$vehicles = array();
$all_words = array ("123", "apple", ”orange”, ………, ”bannana”, ”123”, ”654”, ”car”, ”bus”, ………, ”train”, ”bike”, ”654”); 
//continuous ……… Indicate there can be unknown amount of array elements.
//Also, these numeric values of 123 and 645 can be changed to something convenient
```

I can see that using `$fruits = array_slice($array, 1, 5)`   I can get a portion of this array in to a new one. But if I don’t know the length of array between two numbers(`123` and `654`, how can I assign these values in to an new array?

Comment: Thanks for all of your detailed answers and comments. it helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get their index using `array_search()` and then use them for slicing, like this..

```
$index1 = array_search('123', $all_words); 
$index2 = array_search('654', $all_words); 
$vehicles = array_slice($array, $index1, $index2-$index1+1);
```

Comment: no reason to upvote, you forgot to +1 each index, because `array_search` will return `0` in this example but you need `1` for `array_slice`

Answer (score 0):

`$fruits = array_slice($array, array_search('123', $array)+1, array_search('654', $array)+1)`